# unable to add download new virtual device in genymotion

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I'm trying to add new virtual device in genymotion but while downloading the device, there comes an error message saying `The file is corrupt. Do you want to download the file again?`  and selecting yes doesn't solve the issue either, the same dialog pops up again.

This is what it looks like[image: Dialog that appears while downloading]

How do I resolve this?

I have installed virtual box version 5.0

Comment: Is the progress bar at the bottom doing anything before this message appears?

Comment: No. Just sliding at 0%

Answer (score 1):

did you update the latest version of genymotion, and did you check your windows update setting is enabled and works? sometimes it give error because of versions .. uninstall and install it and be sure selected personel using before install..

Comment: I'm on ubuntu. I've installed the latest version of genymotion. also, tried completely removing it and reinstalling again. Though I'm not sure about personal usage. I think i selected for all users.